# Use CSS and HTML to set parent container to content height minus X pixels

Tags: html, css, height, line-height

I have a HTML setup:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex corporis perferendis in fugiat cumque. Ipsam modi quia doloremque, animi quisquam quo exercitationem nihil debitis ea corrupti, provident placeat officiis nam.
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the height of the div with id `wrapper` to be equal to the height of the div with id `content`, minus X px (say 4px).

The div with id `wrapper` must be positioned according to the normal flow of the document. I.e. not `absolute` or `fixed`.

Is this possible?

---

I am asking because I would like to remove the top and bottom spacing of the text, (not padding, border, margin), but keep spacing between the text in case of wrapping.

Essentially; If the text would never wrap, (which it can), it would be equal to setting the `line-height` to 1 (or the font size).

EDIT: Asked another way, can i set `line-height` to 1 for only the top half of the first line, and the bottom half of the last line?

If there are any other ways of accomplishing this, I.e css properties like `paragraph-height` or similar, this is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand precisely what you need here, but if you want the parent to be the same height as its child but minus a few pixels, you could add a negative margin to the child to reduce the parent's height.

```css
#wrapper{
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#content {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex corporis perferendis in fugiat cumque. Ipsam modi quia doloremque, animi quisquam quo exercitationem nihil debitis ea corrupti, provident placeat officiis nam.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use `calc()` to make calculations.

```css
#content{
  height: calc(100% - 4px)
}
```

Comment: That would make it the height of the wrappers container, not the height of the inner text as they wanted.

Comment: I noticed that too. I edited my answer a bit. The main point of the solution was anyways how to use calculations in CSS